# Keywords in different languages

Tags: seo, internationalization, translation

I have a website which is mainly photos, and not a lot of text, except maybe landmark names (eiffel tower, hoover dam, etc) depending on what the user uploads.

in SEO in english it works fine (if people search in English they find what they are looking for). But this works for people that search in English. A large segment of users are tourists that usually search in their own language (French, Spanish, etc) and so it doesn't come up in the search results.

Creating a separate page for the photos per language is pretty pointless since it's all photos and barely any text (and also website is not i10n-ed or i18n-ed)

But I do want that searching some predefined terms in other languages (I will write the translations) will appear in search results.

Since using the keywords meta tags is useless, what are my options?

Answer (score 1):

Why creating pages for each language is pointless?

That is the only way of doing it, you can put your keywords to same page in every language, but that looks bad and you might get penalized by Google too.

Istockphoto for an example has separate pages for different languages too. To be more precise they have them under different subdomains.